# Why can't I select which site to migrate to?

Tags: support

When I do an off-topic VTC and select "belongs on another SE site" the box to select which site it should be migrated to only contains meta.aviation.SE. Do you need to have a certain amount of rep in the other site or something?

Comment: [Related, specifically Travel.se](http://meta.aviation.stackexchange.com/q/1492/1696)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Closing as "belongs on another StackExchange site"](http://meta.aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/2852/closing-as-belongs-on-another-stackexchange-site)

Answer (score 5):

The short answer is "We haven't set up any migration paths yet - the lazy-ass moderation staff should get to work on that!"

The longer answer is we've been kind-of ignoring the issue since we really don't have a lot of migration-worthy questions that would get kicked to another site as good/answerable questions, and when they come up they can be flagged and mods can tidy them up (fixing comments and such) before we send them to a good home.

---

If you make a good case for specific migration paths (Travel and Space both seem like good candidates) here on meta we can poke the developers to set them up, but unless we're seeing a good trend of accepted migrations to another site we can probably keep working with the "Flag-and-we'll-deal-with-it" migration system.
For reference there have been 2 migrations in the past 90 days: 1 to Travel, and 1 to Engineering - it's not like the volume is killing us :)

Comment: So, do a VTC off-topic then flag for a mod, or just the VTC and you guys will check it?

Comment: @TomMcW Just a flag will get our attention - VTC will put it in the queue and we may see it there too, but the flag guarantees one of us will *have* to look at it to make the little blue counter icon go away :)

Comment: Nobody wants a blue counter icon! Those are the worst!